# Why localhost is too slow while I am downloading and it works perfect when there's no internet at all

Tags: php, localhost, wamp

My project don't need anything from the internet, no JQuery, no twitter, no nothing! and it works perfectly when there's no internet connection at all, and of course when there's an internet connected. The problem is when I am downloading something from the internet my localhost become very slow! any advice other than stop downloading while you are working?
I am using:
Wamp, windows 7 64bit

Answer (score 0):

The networking stack is still involved in a localhost lookup (For one thing it may be set to any ip address in your hosts file). A forum post [here](https://learningnetwork.cisco.com/thread/4161) suggests even the NIC is involved.

> On a PC when you ping your Loopback the NIC is involved down to the NDIS(network driver interface specification), which is the driver software for the NIC and resides between Internet/Data Link layer. This driver is responsible for allowing multiple protocol stacks i.e. IPX/SPX, TCP/IP to coexist. So the ping doesn't actually get framed and sent out on the wire. It simply "polls" the appropriate stack driver to see if it is configured and able to respond to requests.

This would indicate that if your download is using all/most of the resources of the NIC you could see decreased performance.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid `localhost` and use `127.0.0.1` , which is the loopback adress, and as stated in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback):

> *In TCP/IP a loopback device is a virtual network interface implemented in software only and not connected to any hardware*

In contrary the `localhost` will involve more work as it has to go through the routing table, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) .